# What is xdg-icon-resource doing in addition to moving icons to destination?

Tags: xdg

Installing icons manually by copying files to `/usr/share/icons/hicolor/256x256/apps/My256pxSquareIcon.png` and using

`sudo xdg-icon-ressource install --theme hicolor --context apps --novendor --mode system --size 256 ./My256pxSquareIcon.png My256pxSquareIcon` doesn't result in the same thing.

The second allow to just use `Icon=My256pxSquareIcon` inside a `.desktop` file and allow the dynamic use of different resolutions icons when available to best suit the situation while the first require to use the full path of the icon.

What is xdg-icon-ressource doing in addition to copying the file to the icon path to allow this ?

Comment: You can read the script [here](http://portland.freedesktop.org/xdg-utils-1.1.0-rc1/scripts/xdg-icon-resource) (I'm too lazy to do it)... I'll take a wild guess and say it updates the icon cache.

Comment: Looks like that's the thing

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/icons
manual section could be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

[It `touch`es a file](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/xdg/xdg-utils/tree/scripts/xdg-icon-resource.in?h=v1.1.3#n64) in the installation directory to change the directory `mtime`.   Gtk+, for example, checks to see icon directories are updated or not in [gtkicontheme.c::rescan_themes()](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/blob/3.23.1/gtk/gtkicontheme.c#L2732).

So, to emulate `xdg-icon-ressource` in your example, just do the following:

```
$ sudo touch /usr/share/icons/hicolor/
```

You can make sure that the directory's `mtime` is changed with `stat` before and after `touch`.

```
$ stat /usr/share/icons/hicolor/
  File: /usr/share/icons/hicolor
  Size: 4096        Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: 10302h/66306d   Inode: 27002061    Links: 19
Access: (0755/drwxr-xr-x)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2018-08-27 19:01:50.000000000 +0900
Modify: 2018-08-27 19:01:50.000000000 +0900
Change: 2018-08-27 19:01:50.437962154 +0900
 Birth: -
```

Check the line starting with "`Modify:`".